# How to access attributes in freemarker liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, freemarker

I have a request object that contains complete url

The structure is

```
 +-portlet-session

 +-attributes

  +- COMPLETE_URL
```

I can access portlet-session using

> request['portlet-session']

How can I access the attribute COMPLETE_URL

I have tried -

> request['portlet-session']['COMPLETE_URL']

but doesnt work

Any help? I am using liferay 6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out

> request["attributes"].CURRENT_COMPLETE_URL

Comment: Which is nicer to write as `request.attributes.CURRENT_COMPLETE_URL` BTW.